Como enviar datos a mi base de datos en sql server desde un boton?
Estoy haciendo un Proyecto ASP.Net utilizando SignalR y quiero que cada vez que pulse el botón enviar, guarde el usuario, la fecha hora y el mensaje enviado en la tabla de mi base de datos.
Ahora la tengo que cuando le doy a enviar se queda solo en esa sala y cada una es individual, pero cuando abre la sala en otra pestaña no aparece lo que escribí anterior mente.
Como puedo hacer que se guarden los datos en la base de datos y así cuando habrá la sala en otra pestaña se quede lo que ya había escrito antes?
Mi estado actual:
la pagina:

Mis archivos de proyecto:

Clase Program.cs:
using Chat_Room.Controllers.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Owin;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production 
scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");

app.Run();

public class Starup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var slqConnectionString = @"Server=DESKTOP- 
    ULD6KO5;Database=DBChat_Grupar;Integrated Security=True;";
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(slqConnectionString);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
  }

el cuerpo de la pagina:
@model int

<h1>@Chat_Room.Controllers.ChatController.Rooms.GetValueOrDefault(Model)</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           placeholder="usuario"
           id="user" />
    <br />

    <input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           placeholder="texto"
           id="message" />
    <br />

    <div class="text-center">
        <button id="btnSent"
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-success">
            Enviar
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
    <div id="messages"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <div id="notifications"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>

<script>

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chat").build();

connection.start().then(() => {
    connection.invoke("AddToGroup", "@Model")
}).catch((e) => console.error(e));

document.getElementById("btnSent").addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    let room = "@Model";
    let user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    let message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    connection.invoke("SendMessage", room, user, message).catch((err) => 
console.error(err.toString()));

    document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    document.getElementById("message").focus();
    event.preventDefault();

})

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => {
    var message = "<div ><b>" + user + " dice: </b>" + message + "</div>";

    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = message + 
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML;
});

</script>

Clase ChatHub:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Owin;

namespace Chat_Room.Controllers.Hubs
{
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string room, string user, string 
message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(room).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, 
message);
    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(string room)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, room);

        await Clients.Group(room).SendAsync("Showwho",
            $"Alguien se conecto {Context.ConnectionId}");
    }

    

   

}


}


Si no sabes por dónde empezar, StackOverflow no es el lugar para obtener esa información. Google es tu amigo, hay muchos sitios con tutoriales, videos, blogs, y más que te ayudarán a conocer las distintas formas de lograr esto que buscas. En cambio, si tienes un problema específico o un error, entonces te hace falta indicar eso en tu pregunta, que probablemente tiene mucho código. Tus probabilidades de obtener ayuda aumentan si lo reduces a un [mcve]. Un saludo.
